# Is this the right code to find out which state start out with first two letters in VB?

Tags: vb.net

This is the code from my textbook to find out which state begin with the first two letters.

```
Dim letters As String=mtbFirstTwoLetters.Text.ToUpper
Dim i As Integer=0
Do Until(CStr(lstStates.Items(i)).ToUpper>letters)  Or(i=lstStates.Items.Count-1)
   i +=1
Loop
If CStr(lstStatesItems(i)).ToUpper.StartsWith(letters) Then
   txtOutput.Text=CStr(lstStates.Items(i))&" begins with " & mtbFirstTwoLetters.Text & ". "
Else
  txtOutput.Text="No state begins with " & mtbFirstTwoLetters.Text & ". "
End If
```

I think the position with loop is wrong, it will loop until it find a state whose name exceeds the sought-after letters alphabetically.

I think it should be

```
Dim letters As String=mtbFirstTwoLetters.Text.ToUpper
Dim i As Integer=0
Do 
   i +=1
Loop Until(CStr(lstStates.Items(i)).ToUpper>letters)  Or (i=lstStates.Items.Count-1) Or (CStr(lstStatesItems(i)).ToUpper=letters)

If CStr(lstStatesItems(i)).ToUpper.StartsWith(letters) Then
   txtOutput.Text=CStr(lstStates.Items(i))&" begins with " & mtbFirstTwoLetters.Text & ". "
Else
  txtOutput.Text="No state begins with " & mtbFirstTwoLetters.Text & ". "
End If
```

Which on is right and why?

=====================
UPDATED

I really can't understand the logic behind 1st, it find out the state whose name exceeds the sought-after alphabetically, but what if the state I want is **EFA** and the state next to it is **FFA** and the 1st code find **FFA**, it does not make sense to me.

UPDATE2

```
Do Until(CStr(lstStates.Items(i)).ToUpper>letters)  Or (i=lstStates.Items.Count-1) Or (CStr(lstStatesItems(i)).ToUpper=letters)
       i +=1
Loop
```

Do I still need to set i=-1 right now?

Comment: Why can't you run it yourself to see which one works?

Comment: Do you want an answer to your question or a better way to do it?

Comment: @Steve I want to know the logic and reason behind it.

Comment: @Steve See the updated question, Sir. And I still can't figure out why second one is wrong, the first one does not skip the first element?

Comment: Well tested a bit the code above and you are right, The first loop finds a state only if it is the last item in the listbox. However, the second loop fails to find the state that is the first item in the listbox. You should start with i=-1.

Comment: @Steve Thanks, I got it now, what a silly mistake, I should start with -1.

Comment: @steve Sir, what if I put `Until(CStr(lstStates.Items(i)).ToUpper>letters)  Or (i=lstStates.Items.Count-1) Or (CStr(lstStatesItems(i)).ToUpper=letters)` to the top, do I still need to set i=-1? Please see the question updated 2, thank you.